# ¿Como quitar index.php de la URL en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache

Instale el proyecto en los servicios web de Amazon (AWS) en una instalación de Ubuntu, pero para poder acceder al sistema las URL's deben tener incluir **index.php**, como esta:

```
/public/index.php/login
```

El .htaccess que tiene Laravel por defecto no fue modificado ni nada y en mi `localhost` funcionan perfectamente sin necesidad de **index.php**, por lo que pienso que debe ser una configuración del servidor, pero por mas que busco no encuentro que debo modificar.

¿Alguna idea de que se deba modificar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel incluye un archivo `public/.htaccess` que se usa para proporcionar URL sin el controlador frontal `index.php` en la ruta.

Antes de servir `Laravel` con `Apache`, debes asegurarte de **[habilitar el módulo `mod_rewrite`](https://www.galisteocantero.com/activar-modulo-mod_rewrite-de-apache-en-linux-y-windows/) para que el archivo `.htaccess` sea aceptado por el servidor**.

---

Si el archivo `.htaccess` que se incluye con `Laravel` no funciona con tu instalación de `Apache`, puedes probar esta alternativa:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

---

#### Referencia:

- [Laravel > Web Server Configuration > Pretty URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#pretty-urls)